# Good Practice of Object Initialising IN TDD

Tags: tdd

I just start working on TDD but i just need to know couple of things about object initializing in setup or local method.

Let me explain bit more'.

**Case 1:**

```
Public Class TestCase{
 LoginClass obj;
  public void TearUp(){
   obj = LoginClass
  }

public void TearDown(){
dispose(obj);
}
```

**Case 2:**

```
 Public Class TestCase2{
    public void Validate(){
     LoginClass obj = new LoginClass();
   }
     public void ValidateSharepoint(){
     LoginClass obj = new LoginClass();
   }

}
```

So, There are two cases 
Case 1: Object is initializing setUp method and dispose off TearDown Method. 
Case 2: Object is initializing locally in methods.

Both are doing same work but both have different cycle.

**Which case follows the best practice?**

Comment: add tag for the language, since the answer can differ

Answer (score 2):

I would tend to avoid using setup and teardown methods. They can help to reduce the code in your test classes but tend to hide detail from developers who need to modify your code in the future. As code is read way more than it is changed anything you can do to make it easier to read is going to help. I would stick to initializing the object in a factory method.
e.g. CreateValidator() using defaults for dependencies (usually mocks). Better still follow the Test Data Builder pattern (Fluent Builder). A quick search on Google will show you an example of this. If you have access to PluralSight, Mark Selman has an excellent video on Advanced Unit testing which may help you.

Answer (score 1):

If the class being tested is initialized the same way in every test case I find it better to put the initialization inside the `SetUp` method, or at least its default initialization to save redundant meaningless code from the test cases.

If you find yourself initializing the class differently every test you better create Initialization methods -
like `InitializeUnauthorizedUser()` or even better, as Andrew said, use the Test Data Builder pattern as exemplified [here](http://www.robbagby.com/posts/using-the-builder-pattern-in-tests/).

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact a very tedious question, and there is no correct way to do it.
As Andrew points out, try to avoid to put too much into setup or teardown.

On the other hand, if your system is complicated, this can often lead to doing the same stuff over and over again.

If you work in a team, the best is to decide "what is the team's feeling of what is well-known/obvious" during set up - these things can be put into the setup method, and will save work for everyone.

If you work on your own, then you need to discuss this with yourself.
You probably go through different iterations before you find a good balance for your system.